# Checkout Code from CodePlex to remote SVN

Tags: svn, repository, codeplex, svn-checkout

Hi I need to checkout one project maintained on CodePlex to our private repository - SVN hosted on another server.

Is there any way using which I can directly checkout code from CodePlex to a hosted SVN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can't checkout from repository to repository directly (checkout transfer from repository to Working Copy only)
2. If you want to have Read-Only mirror of CodePlex locally - you can try to build [SvnSync](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/svnsync.txt)
3. If you can create local Repository with the same UUID, as CodePlex's repo - you can sync manually (update WC from CodePlex, relocate WC, commit, return to Codeplex binding of WC)